# AWS lambda: Execute function on timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am developing a lambda function that migrates logs from an SFTP server to an S3 bucket.

Due to the size of the logs, the function sometimes is timing out - even though I have set the maximum timeout of 15 minutes.

```
try:
   logger.info(f'Migrating {log_name}... ')
   transfer_to_s3(log_name, sftp)
   logger.info(f'{log_name} was migrated succesfully ')
```

If `transfer_to_s3()` fails due to timeout`logger.info(f'{log_name} was migrated succesfully')` line won't be executed.

I want to ensure that in this scenario, I will somehow know that a log was not migrated due to timeout.

Is there a way to force lambda to perform an action, before exiting, in the case of a timeout?

Comment: "force lambda do something, before timing out?" what does it mean? You can program any logic you want.

Comment: @Dimitris you can increase the lambda function timeout in `Configuration --> General Setting`

Comment: @jebasuthan  My question was not phrased correctly. Will edit it. I have already set lambda timeout to 15 minutes which is the maximum allowed.

Comment: @Marcin Rephrased the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a better way would be to use SQS for that:

```
Logo info ---> SQS queue ---> Lambda function
```

If lambda successful moves the files, it removes the log info from SQS queue. If it fails, the log info persists in the SQS queue (or goes to DLQ for special handling), so the next lambda invocation can handle it.

Comment: Just to understand, do you recommend something like:

`SFTP Server ---> Lambda Function ---> SQS queue ---> Lambda function`
?

I do not quite get it to be honest

Comment: @Dimitris it's not specified in your question how your server works. But if cannot interact with sqs directly, then you can add extra lambda as you described.